# How can I switch weapons on Linux?

Tags: urban-terror

I just downloaded Urban Terror 4.1.1, on Windows it was all fine, but on both Ubuntu 12.04 and latest Arch Linux, I was unable to switch weapons, in the "weapons" dialog, by hitting the slots, e.g main gun, the dialog closes immediately, it doesn't popup the gun list anymore.

Just want to know if anyone has similar issues, and how you went through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A patch to address issues on Ubuntu can be found [here](http://www.urbanterror.info/downloads/security/). Try installing that and seeing if it fixes the problem.